# FCM: High priority scheduled daily notification not working in Android 13

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

When my Samsung device running Android 13 is on sleep for a long very time, my app's notification is not showing, however manually trying to trigger it in Cloud Scheduler Console works and after that real scheduled notification also works. Is there a new restriction again in Android 13 or another doze mode changes? I read something from the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/appstandby#best-practices) that talks about rarity usage and some form of bucket. Is this expected behavior in newer Android specifically 13 and above or depending on manufacturer's implementation which is also mentioned in the document.